# I want to design an adapter from USB to 4.3v and 70mA

Tags: usb, charger, charging

How can I design an adapter between USB and 4.3v and 70mA.  Can I just connect a USB cable to my device that takes 4.3v and 70mA?

Is it likely to damage the device?  I'm looking for a better than 50% chance it will be fine. :)

Comment: The current requirement is fine. USB 3.0 can source up to about 1.5A.

Comment: It depends on the device. Is it more than 5V tolerant?

Comment: 5v to 4.3V : Add a diode between the 5v and your 70 mA load.

Comment: @samuel unfortunately it's a consumer device. I don't think they give out that type of info. Right?

Comment: A schottky diode has a voltage drop of e.g. 0.7V .

Comment: @KnudLarsen: Nooo. A small-signal silicon rectifier. Schottky diodes have a much lower drop at 70mA.

Answer (score 2):

You need an LDO linear regulator like this one: -

[image]

There is an adjustable version: -

[image]

Note pin 4.

But there are plenty to choose from. Try googling "LDO regulator 100mA"

Comment: Wow, thanks for the thorough answer.  I'm not an electrical engineer (background is in Mechanical Engineering) so this is all new to me.  Do I need to connect pin 4 to something?

Comment: I was hoping the I could just connect the wires together and figure the 0.7v difference was within the tolerance of the device input.

Comment: You need to read the data sheet and yes it will connect to a couple of components.